# Where is the class EavSetupFactory defined?

Tags: magento2

I was looking to a code example about creating custom attributes for products. I saw a class/interface in the code (**Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory**). But I could not find where it is defined.

You can see that a lot of plugins have already been using this class/interface, but I could find where it is actually defined.

Where is this class defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento will generate any class with 'Factory' on the end itself either on the fly in developer mode or as part of the `setup:di:compile` process. The factory class will have a method called `create` that will instantiate a new instance of the class on it.

A normal example in a setup class would be as below.

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

class Setup implements InstallDataInterface {

    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) 
    {
         $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetupModel
        */
        $eavSetupModel = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
     }
}
```

This is typically used so that you can load a model using dependency injection. Rather than request `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup`, you request `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory` and then call the create method to get you the `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup` object.

Comment: that's why I didn't find anything when searching the class, been stuck here for a while. Thanks man

Comment: What is the reason that it works this way?

Comment: @robsch When you inject a class into your code via dependency injection, it is a 'shared' object (rather than a newly instantiated object each time - see https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-shared-instances-and-dependency/ for more detail). By injecting a factory object instead, you can create your own instance of the object you need.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. My question was actually about why the Factory classes get generated and are not part in the modules. Feels strange to reference a class that might not be available. I don't see what is special about the Factory class, so that it cannot be part of a magento module.